# Not getting proper value in Camunda BPM when using queryProcessInstancesCount method call

Tags: camunda

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/camunda-rest/engine/default/history/process-instance/count?processInstanceBusinessKey=myApp-201010
```

{
  "count": 1
}
    If I try to get from REST client it is providing me proper output(if the value exist in database). But I need to get the value from Java application using the below code,

```
    ProcessInstanceRestService pIRS=new ProcessInstanceRestService("default");
    ProcessInstanceQueryDto queryParameter=new ProcessInstanceQueryDto();
    List<VariableQueryParameterDto> variables=new ArrayList<VariableQueryParameterDto>();
    VariableQueryParameterDto variableQueryParameterDto = new VariableQueryParameterDto();
    variableQueryParameterDto.setName("processInstanceBusinessKey");//processInstanceBusinessKey
    variableQueryParameterDto.setValue("myApp-201010");
    variables.add(variableQueryParameterDto);
    queryParameter.setVariables(variables);
    queryParameter.setParameter("myApp-201010");
    CountResultDto cRD=pIRS.queryProcessInstancesCount(queryParameter);
    return ""+cRD.getCount();
```

I am getting count as 0 everytime , Please let me know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The business key is not a process variable. Also in the REST URL you query for historic process instances but in the code snipped you use the runtime process instance query. There are setter methods for the business key on both runtime (ProcessInstanceQueryDto#setBusinessKey) and history (HistoricProcessInstanceQueryDto#setProcessInstanceBusinessKey) DTOs.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I have tried to use HistoricProcess Instance Query DTO HistoricProcessInstanceQueryDto hPQD=new HistoricProcessInstanceQueryDto();
  hPQD.setProcessInstanceBusinessKey("myApp-201010"); but how I can get the count from ProcessInstanceRestService. Could you please explan how I can add HistoricProcessInstanceWueryDTO object to ProcessInstanceRestService

Comment: Using HistoricProcessInstanceRestService and HistoricProcessInstanceQueryDto it is achieved. Thanks Sebastian.